# Javascript || e.target and e.value issue

Tags: javascript

Currently I am learning JavaScript from JavaScript & jQuery by Jon Duckett.

Very interesting book and now I am stumped at an exmaple laid down in book in Chapter 6 Events, specifically in exmaple focus-blur.js.

The example is simple, it just shows the working of focus & blur events by calling different functions when those events occur.

My issue arises at line 7 of image attached [issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNR31.png)

My function checkUsername simply doesn't works on blur event.

But, If I replace the code in line 7 by this code `var target = el.value;` the issue gets solved.

Why so?

I've also attached html code below [html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQyId.png)

Comment: Please, write your code into the question instead of linking it as an image.

Comment: Shall do it from next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value` is a property of an element. Element has no `target`.

You are confusing it with an `event`:

```
function checkUsername(event) {
   var target = event.target;
}
```

`event` does have a `target`, which is the element where the event got generated.

See [event.target documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

Answer (score 0):

el is a reference to the text input element.

Input elements of type text have a value property with which you can get / set their content ( == what the user has typed).

=> If you write 'el.value' you get the content of the textbox.
The content is a string which gots a length-property. The length-property is checked in the if-condition ...